# Excel VBA Paste Link Loop

Tags: excel, vba

I'm wanting to move data from multiple sheets into a summary sheet. And want to move it from between the active sheet (which I manually select with my mouse cursor) and the second to last contiguous sheet.
The code below works great but I have 2 problems when the code reaches the paste link lines:

1. The links are only pasted when I'm physically clicked on the "Summary 1819 paper" sheet. This is a problem as the summary sheet gets populated with data from sheets I want to exclude.
2. I used excel 2010 at work to put this code together and it gave me no issues (other than the problem above). However when I've sent the file home, using excel 2016 I'm getting run time errors at random points as the code tries to loop through the paste link lines. At times the error reads "no link to paste" (even though there is) and this is resolved by simply clicking debug and then continue which allows the code to work fine. But at other times it reads "paste method of worksheet class failed" and i'm unable to debug this and the code doesn't continue to execute.

Sub WorkLoop()

```
Dim i As Long
Dim DestRow As Long

For i = ActiveSheet.Index To Sheets.Count - 1

    DestRow = Sheets("Summary 1819 paper").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    Sheets("Summary 1819 paper").Range("B" & DestRow).Value = Sheets(i).Range("C1")
    Sheets("Summary 1819 paper").Range("C" & DestRow).Value = Sheets(i).Range("E1")
    Sheets("Summary 1819 paper").Range("D" & DestRow).Value = Sheets(i).Range("A16")


    Sheets(i).Range("F128").Copy
    Sheets("Summary 1819 paper").Range("E" & DestRow).Select
    Sheets("Summary 1819 paper").Paste Link:=True

    Sheets(i).Range("L7").Copy
    Sheets("Summary 1819 paper").Range("F" & DestRow).Select
    Sheets("Summary 1819 paper").Paste Link:=True

    Sheets(i).Range("M7").Copy
    Sheets("Summary 1819 paper").Range("G" & DestRow).Select
    Sheets("Summary 1819 paper").Paste Link:=True

    Sheets(i).Range("F24").Copy
    Sheets("Summary 1819 paper").Range("L" & DestRow).Select
    Sheets("Summary 1819 paper").Paste Link:=True

    Next i

End Sub
```

I would be grateful for your help in trying to resolve these 2 issues and in understanding what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that the `ActiveSheet.index`does what it says: it looks towards the index of the activesheet. Your code works, which is: run through all sheets, probably because your sheet "summary 1819 paper" is the first worksheet of your workbook.
You want to run through all the sheets except for the first one (your summary sheet) of your workbook? then apply `for i = 2 to sheets.Count` instead of your current `For i = ActiveSheet.Index To Sheets.Count - 1`.

For your second issue. Run through your code step-by-step, using F8. See where it bugs exactly and try to solve it like that. Can't figure it out? Add a "debug.print i" to see on which sheet the error occurs in the direct window. You could also try modifying your

```
Sheets(i).Range("F24").Copy
Sheets("Summary 1819 paper").Range("L" & DestRow).Select
Sheets("Summary 1819 paper").Paste Link:=True
```

to

```
Sheets("Summary 1819 paper").Range("L' & DestRow).Formula = "Sheet"&i&"!F24"
```

Obligatory untested.
Regards,

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. If I exclude all the lines dealing with copy/paste link, the code works fine from any active sheet (which is what i need). I'm adding new sheets to this workbook every week and when I do, I execute the code again to fill the summary sheet with new data. Unless I start from the active sheet (first new sheet I insert), the summary sheet will always get filled with data from older sheets also.

Comment: My second issue with regards to the errors is now resolved. While the code is running if I avoid clicking on anything the code completes without a hitch. I read on here to avoid using 'Select' where possible as this can cause errors if something is clicked when the code is running. Perhaps this is the reason for the errors occurring at random lines though there didn't appear to be a pattern between me clicking and the run time errors occurring